# Retornar somente um item relacionado a tabela principal

Tags: mysql, modelo-relacional, sqlfiddle

Tenho duas tabelas, `respostas` e `respostas_log`, onde eu guardo informações das respostas em respostas e algumas outras que tem que ir logando em respostas_log.
Eu estou precisando no meu SELECT trazer apenas o último log de cada resposta.

Exemplo das tabelas e conteúdo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `respostas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `responsavel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `respostas_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `respostas_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opt_aplicavel` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txt_resposta` text,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `respostas_id` (`respostas_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `respostas` (`id`, `responsavel_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 3);

INSERT INTO `respostas_log` (`id`, `respostas_id`, `opt_aplicavel`, `txt_resposta`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Resposta 1 de 1', '2014-05-13 00:00:00'),
(2, 1, 1, 'Resposta 2 de 1', '2014-05-13 00:00:00'),
(3, 1, 0, 'Resposta 3 de 1', '2014-05-13 00:00:00');
```

E a query que eu tentei

```
SELECT  r.id,
    r.responsavel_id,
    l.opt_aplicavel, 
    l.txt_resposta,
    max(l.id)

FROM respostas r

LEFT JOIN respostas_log l ON l.respostas_id = r.id

GROUP BY  r.id,
    r.responsavel_id,
    l.opt_aplicavel, 
    l.txt_resposta
```

**[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/352d1/4)**

Desse exemplo, seria para trazer somente a primeira e ultima linha

Comment: Dúvidas: (1) quais são a primeira e a última linha, as respostas com id 3 e 2? A query não tem ORDER BY. (2) Não entendi o pedido de "o último log de cada resposta"; as duas linhas que você quer no exemplo não são ambas da mesma resposta?

Comment: Boa @bfavaretto . Se olhar o texto da resposta é a  com 'Resposta 3 de 1' e com valor '(null)'. E esse último log de cada resposta é assim: para todas respostas alguns itens vão para o log de respostas e tenho que exibir somente a última resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá para pegar o id do último log com uma subquery:

```
SELECT  r.id,
        r.responsavel_id,
        l.opt_aplicavel,
        l.txt_resposta,
        l.id idLog
FROM respostas r

LEFT JOIN respostas_log l
  ON l.id = (select max(id) from respostas_log l2 where l2.respostas_id = r.id)
```

Acho que não é possível, em um único `select`, pegar o id o último log e os detalhes deste log.

Para descobrir o valor do último log, você precisará de uma função agregadora (que é o caso do `MAX`). Ao agregar por `id`, os outros campos retornados (`opt_aplicavel` e `txt_resposta`) precisam ser agrupados por cada valor existente. Como agrupar por estes campos faria com que `MAX` retornasse valores diferentes para cada registro, o valor agregado precisa ser obtido em uma consulta separada, e depois usado na consulta que retornará os outros campos.

[Este artigo da documentação do MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) demonstra uma maneira de fazer com que a subquery não seja "correlata" à query principal, o que pode melhorar o desempenho:

```
SELECT  r.id,
        r.responsavel_id,
        l.opt_aplicavel, 
        l.txt_resposta,
        l.id idLog
FROM respostas r

LEFT JOIN (select respostas_id, max(id) id from respostas_log group by respostas_id) l2
  ON l2.respostas_id = r.id

LEFT JOIN respostas_log l
  ON l.id = l2.id;
```

[Ambos os exemplos no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/352d1/37)

Se o desempenho de ambos os casos estiver abaixo do esperado, talvez seja o caso de criar um índice que facilite a consulta.

Comment: Isso funcionou para o que eu preciso, só tenho uma dúvida, isso por acaso não pode deixar a minha query muito lenta ou não preciso me preocupar com isso?

Comment: Editei a resposta para incluir uma alternativa com melhor desempenho.

Comment: Valew mesmo @Dang , estou analisando aqui, mas da primeira forma como passou da para ver que retorna os dados da linha da segunda tabela, no caso, respostas_log.